# create DDL and SQL statement for a 3 tables in a 3F normal model

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I was hoping someone could point me on the write direction as  to solve a problem I was presented in a technical interview writing test; the 3 parts question asked to consider  the 3NF in order to:

1) write a DDL to create   Owner, Dog and Breed Tables
2) write a SQL statement to display ALL of contents of the 3 tables
3) write an optimized design that would simplify querying the tables when looking for Dogs of multiple breeds 
I am afraid that my  answers that follows were incorrect and would appreciated if someone could please shed the light on me :

3)

```
  Create Owner(Owner, D_ID) 
  Create Dog(D_ID, ,B1_ID, B2_ID)
  Create Breed(B_ID, B_Name)
```

2)

```
  Select * from Owner O
  Full Outer Join Dog D on O.D_ID = D.D_ID 
  Full Outer Join Breed B  on D.D_ID = B.B_ID
```

Many thanks in advance and have a nice day

Comment: you should have a bridge table between  dog an owner  ..as it can be 1 to many

Comment: u should have a persion table.. to store owner details

Comment: MySQL and sql-server are not the same, which one are you using?

Comment: if there is possibility of Dogs of multiple breeds in that case one more bridge tabe  for bog&breed relation..

Comment: Can a dog have multiple owners? I don't really think so.

Comment: Hi Chuck, the test didn't say ...

Comment: Sandeep, thank you for you answer

Comment: Strawberry, its a possibility although the test didn't specify it -  so Edu already cover that  possibility

Answer (score 2):

I would create a DogBreeds table to handle the many to many relationship between dogs and breeds, Also I guess a dog has an owner and an onwner can have many dogs (that could be another many to many if a dog may have many owner and viceversa):

3) `Create Owner(O_ID, O_Name) Create Dog(D_ID, D_Name,  O_ID) Create Breed(B_ID, B_Name) Create DogBreeds(D_ID,B_ID)`

2)

```
Select * from Owner O
  Full Outer Join Dog D on O.O_ID = D.O_ID 
  Full Outer Join DogBreeds DB on D.D_ID = DB.D_ID 
  Full Outer Join Breed B  on DB.B_ID = B.B_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1) write a DDL to create Owner, Dog and Breed Tables

I would create it like this:

```
Create Owner(OwnerID, Name)
Create Dog(DogID, Name, OwnerID, BreedID)
Create Breed(BreedID, Name)
```

All tables have IDs and names. An Owner has a name like **John Doe**, a dog has a name like **Max** and the Breed has a name like **Boxer**.

I created a one-to-many relationship between a Dog and a Breed, assuming that one Dog can only have one Breed, but one Breed can be owned by multiple Dogs.

I also created a one-to-many relationship between an Owner and Dog, assuming that one Dog can only have one Owner, but an Owner can have multiple Dogs.

If a Dog can have multiple Owners, then another table would be needed to represent the many-to-many relationship between the Owner and the Dog:

```
Create Owner(OwnerID, Name)
Create Dog(DogID, Name, BreedID)
Create DogOwner(DogID, OwnerID)
Create Breed(BreedID, Name)
```

> 2) write a SQL statement to display ALL of contents of the 3 tables

To get the contents of all 3 tables you should join them with either a INNER JOIN or a LEFT JOIN. The latter is in case you accept NULL values on the OwnerID and BreedID of the Dog table.

```
SELECT 
d.DogID, d.Name, d.OwnerID, d.BreedID,
o.OwnerID, o.Name,
b.BreedID, b.Name
FROM Dog d
INNER JOIN Owner o ON d.OwnerID=o.OwnerID
INNER JOIN Breed b ON d.BreedID=b.BreedID
```

> 3) write an optimized design that would simplify querying the tables
>   when looking for Dogs of multiple breeds:

This is asking for a many-to-many relationship between Dogs and Breeds.

```
Create Owner(OwnerID, Name)
Create Dog(DogID, Name, OwnerID)
Create Breed(BreedID, Name)
Create DogBreed(DogID, BreedID)
```

Now if you want to know the breeds of the Dogs, you can just query:

```
SELECT d.Name AS DogName, b.Name AS DogBreed
FROM DogBreed db
INNER JOIN Dog d ON db.DogID=d.DogID
INNER JOIN Breed b ON db.BreedID=b.BreedID
```